# How to Sum() Distinct Row records

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

I have a table `Purchase_table` i have unique records in it with same Values, so am able to get the unique row using `Group by` Function, but my requirement i want so sum those records and show in single line With Total.

i used this query

```
select date , invoiceno ,orgname as vendor , 
                    invoice_value as taxable_value ,sum(cgst_value) as cgst ,sum(sgst_value)  as sgst ,
                    sum(igst_value) as igst , invoice_value +cgst_value +sgst_value +igst_value as Invoice_value from purchase_table group by invoiceno union all select 'Total', '','', sum(invoice_value), sum(cgst_value), sum(sgst_value), sum(igst_value), sum(invoice_value +cgst_value +sgst_value +igst_value) from purchase_table group by invoiceno order by date, invoiceno
```

**output**

```
[![This is the output of my query having Total in many line, i want the output in one line with all unique qroup by records][1]][1]
```

Comment: Generally, the columns in the SELECT also need to appear in the GROUP BY. Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please add some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You just put limit 1 in the query